# Unable to have the reverse of Ctrl-O in Vim

Tags: vim, buffer, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to have the reverse of

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

to be

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

The original reverse is

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

How can you remap the reverse of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in Vim to be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>?

Comment: This belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/). It has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As shown in help under

```
:help C-o
```

the "reverse" of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: @Idigas: How can you remap the key to Shift-Ctrl-O. I cannot ever remember the C-i.

Comment: @Ruslan `Ctrl-i` and `Ctrl-I` are synonymous

Comment: @törzsmókus no they are not. `Ctrl-I` is equivalent to `Ctrl-Shift-i`. And it doesn't really work to undo `Ctrl-o`, unlike `Ctrl-i`, which does.

Comment: On most terminals, you (or vim) have no way to tell whether the user pressed `Ctrl-i` or `Ctrl-Shift-i`, that's what I meant by ‘synonymous’.  See the link in [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852657/501765) for explanation

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately Vim recognises Control-o and Control-O as synonyms.
There's some information [here](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/cb3afd343edcb9e4?pli=1&safe=on) about why you can't map Control-Shift-o, but it doesn't look like it's possible.

I've upvoted Idigas answer, it's not that hard to remember Control-I.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you use *xterm*, you can get around the terminal emulator limitations by remapping keys in your `.Xresources` file. Use a key sequence that you do not use anyway, for instance C-M-7 (0x9f):

```
XTerm*vt100*translations: #override\n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key> O: string(0x9f)
```

Then do an `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and map C-M-7 to C-i in Vim.

Admittedly it's a hack, but it have helped me a lot. Check out my [.Xresources](http://pastebin.com/ZRczRKsx) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

*Vim* sees <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> because of a limitation with terminal emulators.

Comment: Are there any details about those limitations?

Comment: yes, see the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/yzr9ND7cueQ) in [Andy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852657/501765)